# When i try to create a role it gives me an error (discord.js)

Tags: discord.js

So i am trying to make a command that mute a member. I want my bot to check if there is role name Muted and if there is not, to create a role for Muted members.
This is the code:

```
module.exports = {
name: 'mute',
description: 'mutes a member',
execute(message, args, Discord, bot) {
    let mutedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Muted')

    if(!mutedRole) {
        Guild.roles.create({
            data: {
                name: 'Muted',
                color: 'BLACK'
            }
        })
    }
}
```

}
and the error is this:

```
C:\Users\ADRIAN\Desktop\ZerOne BOT\commands\mute.js:10
        Guild.roles.create({
                    ^
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Comment: What is `Guild`? Where is it coming from?

Comment: Guilds in Discord represent an isolated collection of users and channels, and are often referred to as "servers" in the UI.

Comment: I thought guild was a medieval association.  I asked what `Guild` was in your code. How did you define it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should create a role via code. I think you should create a role in your Discord server (like actually just making one without code). Download the ms package. (npm i ms) Then, paste this code in:

```js
const ms = require('ms');
module.exports = {
    name: "mute",
    description: "Mutes a member!",
    execute(message, args, Discord, bot){
        const target = message.mentions.users.first();
        if (target) {
            let mainRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Member');
            let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Muted');

            let memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);

            if (!args[1]){
                memberTarget.roles.remove(mainRole.id);
                memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole.id);
                message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been muted.`);
                return;
            }

            if (isNaN(args[1]) || !args[1] === ' '){
                message.channel.send("Please enter a real number! (If you have a space after the username and you don\'t want to set a time limit, delete the space. YOU HAVE TO.)");
                return;
            }
            
            memberTarget.roles.remove(mainRole.id);
            memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole.id);
            message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been muted for ${ms(ms(args[1]))}`);

            setTimeout(function(){
                memberTarget.roles.remove(muteRole.id);
                memberTarget.roles.add(mainRole.id);
            }, ms(args[1]));
        } else {
            message.channel.send("Can't find that member!");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to CodeLyon for this code. Hope this works for you! It even includes a time limit.
format 1: !mute @User
format 2: !mute @User 1000 (1000 can be changed, just make sure it's in milliseconds)

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "unmute",
    description: "Unmutes a member!",
    execute(message, args, Discord, bot){
        const target = message.mentions.users.first();
        if (target) {
            let mainRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Member');
            let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Muted');

            let memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);

            memberTarget.roles.remove(muteRole.id);
            memberTarget.roles.add(mainRole.id);
            message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been unmuted.`);
        } else {
            message.channel.send("Can't find that member!");
        }
    }
}
```

format: !unmute @User

Remember, this code only works if you have a role Member and a role Muted. So, in your server, add the role Member to everybody and add a role Muted (not to everybody).

Hope this works! If there's any need for clarification, please tell me in the comments.